# Possible to force unique IDs to variables containing integers between -5 and 256 in python?

Tags: python, variables, operators, unique, identity

I have a class with several named attributes. I would like to be able to pass one of the classes attributes to itself and be able to determine specifically which attribute was passed.

Below is a trivial example of how I was doing it (using the "is" operator), until I discovered that special cached variable IDs are used for integer values between -5 and 256.

```
class AClass:
    def __init__(self, one, two, three):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
        self.three = three

    def getIndex(self, attribute):
        if attribute is self.one:
            return 1
        elif attribute is self.two:
            return 2
        elif attribute is self.three:
            return 3

    def setByIndex(self, i, value):
        if i == 1:
            self.one = value
        elif i == 2:
            self.two = value
        elif i == 3:
            self.three = value

    def setByAttrib(self, attribute, value):
        i = self.getIndex(attribute)
        self.setByIndex(i, value)


object = AClass(0, 0, 0)

object.setByAttrib(object.three, 10)
```

In the above example, the intention is to set ***object.three*** to ***10***. However, since all attributes are pointing to the cached location of integer ***0***, the getIndex function would evaluate true on any of them, and ***object.one*** (which appears first) will get set to ***10***. If the object was initialized with values ***257, 257, 257***, functionality would presumably be as intended.

So the question is, is there a way to either:

a) force the system to assign non-cached, unique memory locations for these attributes (even if they are set between -5 and 256), or

b) use some other method to check if an attribute passed as an argument is uniquely itself?

**EDIT:**

Since it was asked a couple times, one of the reasons I'm using this paradigm is due to the the lack of pointers in python. In the example above, the **setByIndex** function could be doing some complicated work on the attribute. Rather than write multiple identical functions for each variable (eg **setOne, setTwo, setThree**), I can write out a single generic function that is retrieving and setting by index (index is basically acting like a pointer). Yes, I could pass the attribute value as an argument and return the new set value and do the assignment in the scope where the specific attribute is known, but I am already returning a value. Yes, I could return a list, but it adds more complexity.

I do realize that there are better ways to implement what I need (eg key-value pairs for the attributes and index numbers) but it would be a lot of work to implement (thousands of changes). If there was a way to use the varaible ID as my unique identifier and continue to use the "is" operator (or similar), I wouldn't need to change too much. Not looking possible though. Appreciate the comments/responses.

Comment: What is the purpose of `setByAttrib`? Why not just use `object.three = 10`?

Comment: What you desire is not defined in the Python language and subject of every interpreter's implementation. Usually if you desire to change an attribute, you name it. Either by name or by giving a dictionary with key/value or by using `**kwargs`.

Comment: @chepner, Indeed, it is a trivial example. I can't say that there isn't a better way to accomplish what I am actually doing (most of which is working), but that would involve a lot of re-work. Before I go down that road, I want to see if this is possible in concept.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, in hindsight, I should have probably used a dictionary whereby I could have explicitly defined the relationship between the attribute and index. It wasn't necessary in the beginning, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the memory locations, they are simply an implementation detail here. It's really about function design, so if you want to set `object.three`, then do exactly that, otherwise, you can create a mapping to an index if you wanted to:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.one, self.two, self.three, *_ = args

    # get an object by it's index
    def get_by_index(self, index):
        # here's how you could create such a mapping
        opts = dict(zip((1, 2, 3), ('one', 'two', 'three')))

        try:
            return getattr(self, opts[index])
        except KeyError as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Improper alias for attribute, select one of {', '.join(opts)}") from e

    # if you want to set by an index, then do that this way
    def set_by_index(self, index, val):
        opts = dict(zip((1, 2, 3), ('one', 'two', 'three')))

        try:
            setattr(self, opts[index], val)
        except KeyError as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Improper alias for attribute, select one of {', '.join(opts)}") from e



# otherwise, just set the attribute by the name
a = MyClass(0, 0, 0)
a.three = 55
```

The thing is, you're right, `is` will look at the three `0`'s the same way, because it never copied that data in the first place. `one, two, three` point to the same data because they were assigned the same data. Once you assign the attribute again, you've effectively re-binded that attribute to a *new* value, rather than updating an existing one.

Point being, don't worry about *where* the memory is for this implementation, just set explicitly against the attribute

Comment: Thanks for response. The example was trivial, just illustrating the functionality I would need to avoid rewriting large amount of code. I added an example non-trivial usage case in the original question. Anyhow, it sounds like the answer is no and no, which would mean I'll have to make the changes.